# In React after clicking a button I want to change it immediately to the previous state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a code like this in a component;

```
const [loggedOut, setLoggedOut] = useState(false);

function logoutHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoggedOut(true);
}

useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (loggedOut) setLoggedOut(false);
    }, 1);
});
```

When I click the logout button I want it to be true but then immediately to the false like a flip-flop. I accomplished it with the code shown above kind of. But I am not sure that this is the right approach.

Comment: The timeout that you wrote is a bit weird and you don't really want to have code running like that all the time when it doesn't need to. You can just change the `useEffect` ever so slightly to pass in a dependencies array like `[loggedOut]` then just write an if condition in the effect instead like `if (loggedOut) setLoggedOut(false)`

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I should have thought about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to pass timeout when logout change then useEffect work.

```
const [loggedOut, setLoggedOut] = useState(false);

function logoutHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoggedOut(true);
}

useEffect(() => {
   if (loggedOut) setLoggedOut(false);
}, [logout]);
```

Comment: Your welcome please accept the answer for others help as well